# Make an SVG clickable but not draggable using CSS, Javascript

Tags: svg, click, mouseevent

I would like to use a SVG object as a navigation item on a touch screen.

The object should **only accept click events**, but no other events like dragging.

Currently I have two options:

- if I set **pointer-events="none"** then the object is *both not draggable* and *not clickable*. So the href does not work.
- if I remove **pointer-events="none"** then the object is clickable, but most touch screen events register as dragging attempts. So it's hard to perform a valid click.

```
    <a href="step1.html">
        <svg height="200" width="200"  pointer-events="none">
            <polygon points="50,50 25,75 50,100 100,100 200,100 200,50"
                     style="fill:blue;stroke:lightblue;stroke-width:2"/>
            <text x="75" y="85" fill="white" style="user-select: none;">back</text>
        </svg>
    </a>
```

How can I turn this SVG into something at only accepts a click but nothing else?

Note: Replacing the `<a>` tag with javascript is OK.

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to hide SVG behind DIV with near-zero opacity (0.01), so the DIV will receive clicks but the SVG will be still visible